# Showing loading message while creating the transition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, loading, transition

In my JQuery Mobile app, I can show the loading message during the transition between pages, but I can't show it while the transition is prepared.

```
$("#details").bind( "pagebeforeshow", function( e, data ) {
    console.log('details before show');
    $('body').addClass('ui-loading');
});

$("#details").bind( "pageshow", function( e, data ) {
    console.log('details show');
    $('body').removeClass('ui-loading');
});
```

On Android, it takes some ms to create the transition, and the device seems unresponsive during this time.
How can I start the loading message before the transition is set up?

Comment: did you solve this? i'm having a similar problem...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding to pagebeforechange?  I believe that fires before pagebeforeshow, though according to the docs you should be able to do this as you've attempted.

Comment: yes my first try was to bind it to pagebeforechange, but the result was the same.